# What is Mattermost / chat?

Tags: community

In several posts on this CiviCRM StackExchange site, I see references to people getting help via 'Mattermost'.

What is it and how do I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mattermost is open source messaging software - see https://www.mattermost.org/

References to Mattermost within this CiviCRM StackExchange site generally refer to CiviCRM's online community chat system that uses the Mattermost software and is one of the various [support resources for CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/help).

StackExchange uses a Question and Answer format which works well for many things but sometimes an interactive chat format is more appropriate.

You can access it at https://chat.civicrm.org/  Follow the links to create an account.

- It is organised into various public and private channels.  Take note of the description of each channel and post your question in the most relevant one.
- If you're unsure which channel to use, try 'Town Square' or 'User Support'.
- Just ask your question. Don't ask if it's ok to ask.
- Choose the most appropriate channel and ask.  Don't post the same question in multiple channels.
- It is possible to send "Direct Messages" to other users but don't use them, unless you know the person and you are sure they are the only one that can reply.
- Be nice!  It is a community of fellow CiviCRM users who are often very helpful, but do remember no-one is obliged to help you.

Comment: I'd be even more explicit about DM: don't use them, unless you know the person and you are sure that's the only one that can reply

Comment: Good point @Xavier - I've edited to include that.